# Graphene Mutation Tultorial not working

Tags: django, python-3.x, api, graphql

I´ve started learning GraphQL for a week,
and my biggest challenge is dealing with Post Data.
I´ve read that it´s all about mutations, however Im not doig it right.
I´m just trying to post a Survivor(my model)  Object to my database
 Here´s the code:
This is the app´s schema

```
import graphene
from graphene import relay, ObjectType

from graphene_django.types import DjangoObjectType
from graphene_django.filter import DjangoFilterConnectionField

from .models import Survivor

class SurvivorNode(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Survivor
        filter_fields = ['name']
        interfaces = (relay.Node, )



class SurvivorInput(graphene.InputObjectType):

    name = graphene.String(required=True)
    age = graphene.Int(required=True)


class AddSurvival(graphene.Mutation):
    class Arguments:
        survivor_data = SurvivorInput()

    survivor = graphene.Field(SurvivorNode)

    @staticmethod
    def mutate(root,info,survivor_data):
        survivor=Survivor(
            name = survivor_data.name,
            age = survivor_data.age
        )

        return AddSurvival(survivor = survivor)



class Query(object):
    all_survivors = DjangoFilterConnectionField(SurvivorNode)
    survivor = relay.Node.Field(SurvivorNode)
```

Would you guys please tell me what´s wrong?

and what should I do right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in mutate method you need to change

```
survivor=Survivor(
            name = survivor_data.name,
            age = survivor_data.age
        )
```

to this

```
survivor=Survivor.objects.create(
            name = survivor_data.name,
            age = survivor_data.age
        )
```

because you want to create new object of type Survivor.